# How to return a birthday from an SQL statement, given a person's age

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, database

I'm trying to create a filter in ASP.net, where a user can select a certain age and an SQL statement is to return all users who are currently this age, based on a 'DOB' (date of birth) field.

So, for example, lets say that I have a variable `age` which currently holds 23. I've got a field in the database called 'DOB', of type 'date'. How would an SQL statement be written to return all records whose date of birth indicate that they are 23? The DOB format is in YYYY-MM-DD.

Thanks

Comment: What's the data type of the DOB field?  The format only matters if it's a text field, which it most certainly should not be.

Comment: 'date' type! Editing question to reflect this.

Comment: How do you define that someone is 23 years old? Born exactly at `24-Feb-1989`? Born in `1989`? Born before `24-Feb-1989` but after `24-Feb-1988`?

Comment: @ypercube presumably a 23 year old is someone whose 23d birthday is today, or any day after one year ago today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE YEAR(GETDATE() - DATEPART(dy, DOB) + 1) - YEAR(DOB) = 37
```

just change 37 to 23 on your end or better yet use a variable

Here is an example you can run

```
CREATE TABLE #test(DOB DATETIME)

INSERT #test VALUES('19701127')
INSERT #test VALUES('19741127')
INSERT #test VALUES('19740227')
INSERT #test VALUES('19761127')
INSERT #test VALUES('19761127')
INSERT #test VALUES('19701127')


SELECT * FROM #test
WHERE YEAR(GETDATE() - DATEPART(dy, DOB) + 1) - YEAR(DOB) = 37

1974-11-27 00:00:00.000
1974-02-27 00:00:00.000
```

You can also use this more convoluted WHERE clause

```
 SELECT *
        FROM #test
        WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR, DOB, GETDATE()) -
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(mm,DOB) > DATEPART(mm,GETDATE())
       OR (DATEPART(mm,DOB) = DATEPART(mm,GETDATE())
       AND DATEPART(dd,DOB) > DATEPART(dd,GETDATE()))
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 37
```

Comment: This doesn't work for leap years.  For example, someone born on '2011-04-01' (not a leap year)  will be considered to be one year old on '2012-03-31' (a leap year); a day too early.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way to achieve this.

```
DECLARE @age int
DECLARE @dob1 date
DECLARE @dob2 date
SELECT @age = 23
SELECT @dob1 = DATEADD(year, -@age, getdate())
SELECT @dob2 = DATEADD(year, 1, @dob1)

SELECT * FROM <table> 
WHERE DOB BETWEEN @dob1 AND @dob2
```

Comment: In addition to those born on Feb 24 1989, who are 23 today, this would return people born between Feb 25 1989 and Feb 24 1990, all of whom are 22 today.

Comment: @phoog: That is another definition of age. Not very popular I guess, but small children (who want to look older), tend to use this definition :)

Comment: IMHO this is clearer than @SQLMenace's answer; however it's not quite right: BETWEEN is an inclusive operator - you want `DOB >= @dob1 and DOB < @dob2`.  Also it won't work correctly if both today and dob fall on a leap day (29 Feb).

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that both the database column and the `age` variable hold date/time data rather than strings.  I'm also going to assume that the [DOB] values are guaranteed not to have a time component.

You're missing one datum from your specification: the reference date.  In other words, given the age 23, and a bunch of birthdays, you want to know which people are 23 *on a given date*.  You might assume that this would be the current date, but here we'll generalize this to a variable.

Those born on Feb 24 1989 are 23 today; anyone born later is younger.  Those born on Feb 24 1988 or earlier are 24 or older today.  The desired range is therefore Feb 25, 1988 to Feb 24 1989.

```
DECLARE @age int
DECLARE @referenceDate date
DECLARE @rangeEnd date
DECLARE @rangeBegin date

SELECT @age = 23
SELECT @referenceDate = GETDATE()
            --2012-02-24
SELECT @rangeBegin = DATEADD(day, 1, DATEADD(year, -@age-1, @referenceDate))
            --1988-02-25
SELECT @rangeEnd = DATEADD(year, -@age, @referenceDate)
            --1989-02-24

-- EDIT: this expression is incorrect; thanks to ypercube for catching the bug
-- SELECT @rangeBegin = DATEADD(day, 1, DATEADD(year, -1, @rangeEnd))

SELECT * FROM <table> 
WHERE DOB BETWEEN @rangeBegin AND @rangeEnd
```

Comment: +1 from me. You explain how (and what) you are calculating so it's easy to adjust this code. Plus, the query will use an index (if possible) on the `dob` column.

Comment: The best so far, but still doesn't handle leap days.

Comment: I think it should be: `SELECT @rangeBegin = DATEADD(day, 1, DATEADD(year, -@age-1, @referenceDate ))` and the nasty leap years would be OK.

Comment: @Joe using DATEADD should handle leap days, no?

Comment: @ypercube I don't see how that would change the result.

Comment: `SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, DATEADD(year, -1, DATEADD(year, -23, '2012-02-29')))` returns `1988-02-29`

Comment: `SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, DATEADD(year, -24, '2012-02-29' ))` returns `1988-03-01`

Comment: @phoog, apologies, my mistake, this version does handle leap days (I think!). +1

Comment: @ypercube, good catch.  I started out with the `-@age-1` expression, but I thought it was too confusing.  I'll change it back.

Comment: @phoog, no it doesn't handle leap days.  if referencedate is 2012-02-29 and age is 23, then rangeBegin will be 1988-02-29 (should be 1988-03-01).

Comment: @Joe I changed it thanks to ypercube's suggestion; I think it now does handle leap days.

Answer (score 0):

Those who where born the same date as today, exactly `@age` years ago:

```
WHERE dob = DATEADD( year, - @age, GETDATE() )
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way for it to be general, i.e. not just born today?

Comment: @Sean: Do you mean to find everyone born in any date of `1989` (for 23 years)?

Comment: I'm trying to return all people within the database who are 23, when all I've got in the database is their DOB.

Comment: someone born before Feb 24 would be 24 not 23

Comment: SQLMenace: What do you mean? If someone is born on `1989-02-24` would be exactly 23 years old (or 23 years and a day, depending on your timezone).

Comment: I said `before` not `on` Feb 24..try January 2nd 1989..that person would be 24 not 23

Comment: @SQLMenace no, someone born on Feb 23d 1989 had their 23d birthday yesterday, and they'll be 23 for nearly another year.

Comment: @Sean: Again, what do you mean with *"people who are 23"*, how do you calculate a person's age? This may seem a dumb question but it's not. As it is obvious by the comments...

Answer (score -1):

If the DOB field is a date field, you can do some date comparisons to get what you want.

```
SELECT user, DOB FROM yourtable 
WHERE MONTH(CURDATE())=MONTH(DOB) AND 
DAY(CURDATE())=DAY(DOB) AND YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(DOB)=23;
```

Comment: You're assuming it's MySQL, but in fact it's MS SQL Server. There's no `CURDATE()`, but there is `GETDATE()`.

Comment: No, that will return all people who are celebrating their 23rd birthday today, not all people who are currently 23.